# Spring AOP Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am running into an issue and still not able to figure it out how to achieve this. Can anyone please help me on this.

I have an existing application which have around 10 JSPs and total more than 200 requests (both read, write and update), that mean we have 200 methods in 10 different spring controller classes. Now because of some security issue, I have to write a new controller (not a simple java, because I need to read some data from a jsp and request/session) and I want to call that new controller before each request, that means I want to call a method in the new controller before any execution of any GET or POST methods in my existing controller classes.

I think I have to use AOP, but not sure how to configure. any example would be a great help.

Comment: You should be using servlet filters.

Comment: And perhaps just Spring Security out-of-the-box.

Comment: @JerinJoseph: Yes, I am using Filters. Here is the details about the issue and what I have tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470725/spring-mvc-security-token-based-authentication

Comment: Not sure why I got a -1 for this question. Could anyone please tell me why, so that I will keep in mind in next time.

Comment: @chrylis: Yes, I am using Filters. Here is the details about the issue and what I have tried so far.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470725/spring-mvc-security-token-based-authentication

Comment: @Jobin: I saw that example, but I need to execute a spring controller (not a simple java method)

Comment: You might want to have a look at spring mvc interceptor

Answer (score 0):

If you are well-versed with Spring AOP, and only want to use it without any alternative,Then you should use **Before** annotation from Aop.

You want to execute it for every operation in your application, then define it as a Java class, and define the bean in Xml file.

@Aspect()
Public Class MyAopClass
{

@Before("someMethod()")
public void doBeforeTask(){
 ...
}

//pointcut execution for all classes in all packages and for methods with any //no of params 
@Pointcut("execution(* com.packages.*.*(..))") 
private void someMethod() {}

}

For more info, refer this link regarding configuration and definition of Aspects.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aspectj_based_aop_appoach.htm

Comment: it is not showing pointcut as i have written ,... this should be used -> @Pointcut("execution(* com.packages.*.*(..))")